# How to count the number of categories that fulfill a certain criteria in Excel?

Tags: excel, count, categories

Consider the following table:

```
ID  Fruit       Quality
-----------------------
1   Banana      good
2   Banana      bad
3   Banana      good
4   Banana      good
5   Mellon      bad
6   Mellon      good
7   Mellon      good
8   Mellon      bad
9   Apple       bad
10  Apple       bad
11  Apple       bad
12  Apple       bad
13  Orange      good
14  Orange      good
15  Orange      good
16  Orange      good
```

In Excel I want to count the number of fruit types that have at least two items with `bad` quality.

In the small example, the result should be `2` since only `Mellon` and `Apple` have at least two `bad` items (while `Banana` has only one and `Orange` none).

**Edit**

I used the solution below with `;` delimiters and without a check for the headings:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B2;B2;$C$2:$C2;"bad")=2;1;"")
```

Comment: What have you tried? `CONTIFS()`?

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks. I thought about it. But `COUNTIFS()` counts if a certain cell or range of cells fulfills a certain criteria. I don't see how one can count by categories using `COUNTIFS()`. But any suggestions very welcome.

Comment: the easiest to use a helper column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a helper column in D2 put this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$1:$B2,B2,$C$1:$C2,"bad")=2,1,"")
```

And copy down.  Then sum the column

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, Excel complains that the formula contains an error. So I cannot even enter it. Maybe I could fix the problem if you could explain what the formula is supposed to do? I can't see how it is supposed to work. Unfortunately, I also don't see why Excel is complaining...

Comment: What is highlighted when you hit okay on the warning?  Are your delimiters `;` instead of `,`?

Comment: [countifs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)  Not sure what else you want to know.

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out. It looks at the content of the fruit column and then looks from there all the way to the top of the column for the combination of that fruit and the bad quality. If this is fulfilled exactly two times, then it writes down a 1. (If its more then 2 times it does nothing since the criterium of at least two bad quality of the fruit will already be fulfilled and counted.)

Comment: Yes it is always looking from the current row up. So the count only equals two once.

Comment: So actually it goes a bit too high. It should only go up to the second row. Otherwise it could count the table headings if they fulfill the criteria.

Comment: They do not meet the criteria in your example. If they do in your actual data then yes you will want to start with the second row not the first.

Comment: I think it would be good to change the formula. That would make it easier for others to figure out how it works. I first thought it has something particular to do with the header...

Comment: No as it is perfectly fine for the dataset you provided.